# Loading a Qt .pro file in VS2010 from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

Is there a way to load a .pro file as a VS 2010 solution from the Command line?

If the Qt AddIn is installed, we can open a .pro file as a Solution, from inside VS 2010. The question is if this is possible from the Command Line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use
  qmake -tp vc foo.pro
to create a .vcproj file, then open that file with Visual Studio on the command line.

The "-tp vc" means "turn TEMPLATE=app into TEMPLATE=vcapp".

Comment: I suppose he wants to open the .pro file directly, which seems to work with his Qt AddIn. But probably that just does what you suggested behind the scenes.